# How to draw a line with arrow end in ios animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-2d

```
// Layer that I am using with round end
CAShapeLayer * energy = [CAShapeLayer layer];
energy.frame       = CGRectMake(20.78, 205.34, 266.17, 230.29);
energy.lineCap     = kCALineCapSquare;
energy.lineJoin    = kCALineJoinRound;
energy.fillColor   = nil;
energy.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.754 green: 0.832 blue:0.183 alpha:1].CGColor;
energy.lineWidth   = 20;
energy.strokeEnd   = 0;
energy.path        = [self energyPath].CGPath;
[self.layer addSublayer:energy];
_energy = energy;

// Stroke drawing with the specific layer as a form of customized circle 
- (UIBezierPath*)energyPath{
UIBezierPath *energyPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[energyPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 5)];
[energyPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(150.639, 0.091) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(3.094, 0.091) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(147.602, -0.114)];
[energyPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(266.168, 115.038) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(215.229, 4.442) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(266.168, 54.243)];
[energyPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(141.441, 230.294) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(266.168, 178.692) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(210.325, 230.294)];
[energyPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(16.757, 116.861) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(72.556, 230.294) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(16.757, 180.515)];
[energyPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(16.615, 115.147) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(16.757, 114.621) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(16.615, 117.387)];
[energyPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(16.615, 102.997) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(16.615, 113.206) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(16.543, 104.194)];
[energyPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(16.736, 96.073) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(16.809, 99.79) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(16.736, 106.391)];
return energyPath;
}
```

I need to use arrow end with the layer stroke end animation. Can anybody please help me what to do. I've designed a shape with the combination of line, Circle and again line at end. I am using stroke end with the stroke width of 15 and I am trying to start from left and the line is filling towards the another end. But I need to add Arrow shaped progression in this shape

Comment: To draw shapes use CoreGraphics

Comment: @PradheepNarendran please edit your question and past the code in the question not hear, it is used to add comments not code ..

Comment: @Shan I did it. Now check it once